# HackerRank - Minimum Swaps 2 Timeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

This challenge asks that you find the minimum number of swaps to sort an array of jumbled consecutive digits to ascending order. So far my code passes most of the tests, however there are four that fail due to timeout. Could anyone explain why my code is timing out? Is there a way to make it find an answer faster?

```
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
const min = Math.min(...arr);
let swapCount = 0;
const swap = (array, a, b) => {
    let test = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = test;
}
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]!==i+min){
        swap(arr, i, arr.indexOf(i+min));
        swapCount++;
    }
}
return swapCount;
}
```

I thought it was a good solution since it only has to iterate over the length of the array once? I'd love to be able to understand why this isn't performing well enough

Comment: Idk how much it's going to impact performance, but when dealing with large arrays its best to create a variable for the array length so that the `array.length` property only gets accessed once.

Comment: @Ameer didn't quite work unfortunately, but thank you for the optimization tip! I'll be using that from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Your big issue is with the call to `arr.indexOf`, as that has to scan the entire array each time you do a swap. You can work around that by generating a reverse lookup from value to array index before starting to sort, and then maintaining that list during the sort. Note that you don't need to do a full swap, only copy the value from `arr[i]` to its correct place in the array since you don't revisit a number once you have passed it. Also you don't need `min`, as under the conditions of the question it is guaranteed to be 1, and you don't need to look at the last value in the array since by the time you get to it it has to be correct.

```js
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
  const indexes = arr.reduce((c, v, i) => (c[v] = i, c), []);
  const len = arr.length - 1;
  let swapCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== i + 1) {
      arr[indexes[i+1]] = arr[i];
      indexes[arr[i]] = indexes[i+1];
      swapCount++;
    }
  }
  return swapCount;
}

console.log(minimumSwaps([7, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(minimumSwaps([4, 3, 1, 2]));
console.log(minimumSwaps([2, 3, 4, 1, 5]));
console.log(minimumSwaps([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should flip function not search function.

```
function minimumSwaps($arr) {
$outp = 0;
$result = array_flip($arr);
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
   if($arr[$i] != $i +1){
        $keyswp = $result[$i + 1];
        $temp = $arr[$i];
        $arr[$i] = $i + 1;
        $arr[$keyswp] = $temp; 
        $tempr = $result[$i + 1];
        $result[$i + 1] = $i +1;
        $result[$temp] = $keyswp;
        $outp = $outp + 1;
    } 
}
return $outp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution , it is similar to Nick's except instead of the Array.Proptytype.indexOf method I used an object literal to map the indices of each value for a better Time complexity since search in object literal is O(1) (You can use ES6 maps too). Here is the code

```js
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
    
    let count = 0;
    let search = arr.reduce((o, e, i) => {
        o[e] = i
        return o
    }, {})
    
    

    for(let i =0 ; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
        let j = search[i+1]
        
        if(arr[i] !== i+1) {
            [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]
            
            search[arr[i]] = i;
            search[arr[j]] = j;
            count += 1
        }
        
    }
    
    console.log(arr)
    return count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, you shouldn't use the `indexOf` method as it makes your solution `O(n^2)` (As the `indexOf` method has to scan the entire array again). You can create a position map array before hand and use it later during the swap. It will keep your solution linear. Here is the [detailed explanation and solution to the HackerRank Minimum Swaps 2 Problem in java, c, c++ and js](http://%20https://www.techrbun.com/hackerrank-minimum-swaps-2/), using this method.